# Memory management and ownership when returning an NSString from a method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'm writing a method in Objective-C which is to return a string based on an NSMutableArray input.  I don't intend for the callers to modify the string but couldn't care less either.  The method's current signature reads as:

```
- (NSMutableString *) generateString:(NSMutableArray *)myArray
```

The project is currently a command-line Foundation Tool in order to learn the ropes but this will ultimately end up in an iPhone application.

My questions are:

1. Would it be more prudent to return an NSString?

2) When returning the NSMutableString should I use autorelease?  If you're recommending I return an NSString how does that modify returning it?

3) If I also want to return an error object identifying if an error occurred, perhaps an enum and a string how does ownership work in that case?  The method isn't called alloc, new or copy so how would the caller know?  How would I return the allocated error object in addition to the string in the above method?

Thanks!

Comment: just a note, don't know if it's relevant to you but you can get a `NSString` from an `NSArray` like this: `NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`

Comment: Thank you filipe, I did not know that.  It's a slick idea but won't work for me in this case as there is necessary logic influencing how the final string is produced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I would return a `NSString` in most cases. It has a slightly smaller memory footprint and if the caller needs a mutable copy, creating one is just a method away: `mutableCopy`.
2. You not only should but **have to** autorelease the `NSString` or `NSMutableString` your method returns (at least if you name your method like in the example)! The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) lists rules you must follow to avoid a complete mess and explains everything in-depth. So read it!
3. The Foundation framework uses the `NSError` class to describe errors. To "return" additional parameters your method would look like this:

   ```
   - (NSString *)generateString:(NSMutableArray *)myArray error:(NSError **)error
   {
       BOOL failed;
       // Do some fancy stuff, if the operation fails, failed is true
       if (failed == YES) {
           if (error != NULL) {
               *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"your_domain" code:123 userInfo:nil];
           }
           return nil;
       }

       return [yourString autorelease];
   }

   // ...

   // Calling your method
   NSError *error = nil;
   [someObject generateString:someArray error:&error];
   ```

Note the two `**` and that any `NSError` var may be `NULL` and not `nil` (so you should check for this in the method's body).

Comment: Note that that should be `*error = [NSError`, not `&error = [NSError`.  Also, you should still return nil even if `error == NULL`--I usually use two nested `if`s to handle this sort of case.  Thinkos strike down the best of us, though--I'm guessing that's what happened here!

Comment: Thanks for the hint – *error is correct, of course -,- Fixed both issues in the code.

Answer (score 1):

By default methods return autorelease NSString, and I'd recomment to use the same behaviour. If you will need to modify resulting string, you can use temporary strings.

Comment: I don't know what you mean "By default methods return autorelease NSString." Where can I see this default behavior?

Comment: Thanks Nickolay but I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by this.  How does this apply to what I'm asking?

Comment: mplappert described this idea in better way )